# Change height makes problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, spectrumjs

I implemented [spectrum color picker](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#options-showAlpha). I'm trying to change the alpha sliders height. (The one with the class name: `.sp-alpha`.) 
When I do that, then the color picker containers (class name: `sp-top-inner`) **height** changes.

How can I edit the [source file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bgrins/spectrum/master/spectrum.js) so that I can change the alpha sliders height without affecting other elements?

Comment: can you post a snippet, simulating your issue?

Comment: It will be difficult to go everywhere around to look the documentation for you. Why don't you post the relevant code here so we can directly see what would be possible to do?

Comment: For every pixel you increase the `.sp-alpha` you need to increase the `bottom` of the `.sp-top-inner`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `.sp-top-inner` height to 150px or add bottom:20px (any number you like):

```
.sp-top-inner {
    height: 150px;
}
```

Or

```
.sp-top-inner {
        bottom: 20px;
    }
```

then change the height of `.sp-alpha` and add custom margin:

```
 .sp-alpha-enabled .sp-alpha {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}
```

**Note**: Just add above codes if you want to enable alpha mode.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/siinsn/r690yf44/)